# In Mkdocs, automatically display all png image files that are in a folder

Tags: mkdocs

How do I get mkdocs to display all png image files that are in a folder? When the images files are changed, I would like mkdocs to update and display these images. In markdown you can explicitly specify a series of files however the names of these png filenames are unknown and will change regularly. I have tried the snippets and superfences extensions. I have also tried the mkdocs-gallery plugin. I can't seem to get any of them to work. Has anyone got an example that I could follow please.

So far in mkdocs-gallery, I have generated this script to detect all images files:

```py
"""
This weeks news......
=====================

"""

import os
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
imgs = []
path = r".\images"
valid_images = [".jpg",".gif",".png",".tga"]
for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))
    display(img)
```

I would like to display the images in one navigation page and not show any code or links to .py files or .ipynb files. Is this possible?

The image below shows the current look of the webpage (but no images are shown). Would mkdocs-gallery be a suitable plugin for this sort of thing?
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on display the images "automatically" and what you tried with mkdocs-gallery plugin. Some [example] would probably show that.